# Need Ansible playbook inorder to calculate number of users currently login into VPN

Tags: networking, ansible, junos-automation

Writing ansible playbook for "Count number of users currently login to VPN".Using Junos modules as suggested by network team.I have installed below softwares on my RHEL 7 machine with Ansible 2.9 version installed.

```
Junos Ansible Requirements
===============================
-->Install Dependencies

# pip install ncclient

# pip install junos-eznc

--> Install Juniper.junos Galaxy role

ansible-galaxy install juniper.junos

---> Have NETCONF enabled on Juniper devices over SSH

# set system services netconf ssh

--->(Optional)

#pip install junos-netconify (python lib for juniper console)
```

---

Whenever i am writing any playbook, I am getting below error.

Playbook:-

```
---
- name: Get device uptime
  hosts:
   - dc1
  roles:
   - Juniper.junos
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: Junos Username
      private: no

    - name: password
      prompt: Junos Password
      private: yes

  tasks:
  - name: get uptime using galaxy module
    junos_command:
      commands: show system uptime
    register: uptime

  - name: display uptimes
    debug: var=uptime
```

## Error:-

```
PLAY [Get device uptime] **************************************************************************************************************

TASK [get uptime using galaxy module] *************************************************************************************************
fatal: [172.16.130.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "invalid rpc for running in check_mode"}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************
172.16.130.1               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I was just exploring ansible networking commands & got above error.Please suggest what configurations required working with junos.

Answer (score 0):

### Please find below playbook to check no. of users currently login to VPN:-

- name: Get system users currently logged in
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:

  - Juniper.junos
    tasks:

    - name: Retrieve facts from device running Junos OS
      juniper_junos_facts:
    - name: Print version
      debug:
      var: junos.fqdn
    - name: Run RPC Commands
      juniper_junos_command:
      commands="show security dynamic-vpn users"
      format=text
      dest={{ junos.fqdn }}.output